# Could installing backup system image on 2nd HD cause problems?

Tags: windows-7, backup, system-restore

**HARDWARE**

I have 3 hard drives installed in my computer:

1. C:/ System 60GB SSD
2. E:/ Media 500GB HHD
3. Z:/ Newly Formatted 240GB SSD (no data)

**FAILURE**

I was experiencing what I thought was a harddrive failure on my Z:/ 240GB SSD, which use to be my main system drive (C:/), so I reinstalled Windows on my smaller 60GB SSD.  I had planned to buy a new SSD to replace the one that failed, but after reformatting and doing a *dskchk (with a scan for bad sectors)* the disk seems to be fine, so it looks like it failed because of logical errors instead of physical errors.

**FAILURE DETAILS**

When applications started locking up, I did an original *dskchk* and found 750kb of bad sectors on my 240GB SSD.  A few months later *Windows Explorer* would lock up within 10 minutes of restarting my computer.  Attempts to do further *dskchk* from boot were incomplete as *dskchk* would always stall on 13% (stage 4 or 5).

I later read somewhere that if *dskchk* stalls it could be caused by corrupt system files (C:\Windows\System32) and to use the *System File Checker* application to check the integrity of the files.  Unfortunately, I read this after reformatting so I'm unsure if that was the problem or not.

**REINSTALL PLAN**

After spending a few hours reinstalled windows (with updates), motherboard and other device drivers on my small 60GB SSD, I created a system image which I plan on installing on my Z:/ 240GB SSD.  Afterwards, I would like to wipe my smaller 60GB SSD and use it as a data drive.

**QUESTIONS**

1. The backup system image is on my E:/ Media drive, but should other drives be plugged in while installing system images?  Should the system image be read from a thumbdrive instead?
2. If I install the system image on my Z:/, will it assign the drive letter C:/ to the drive and create two C:/ drives?
3. What If I unplug my current C:/ drive, reinstall the system image on my Z:/ drive and assign the letter C:/, then replug my other C:/ drive?  Will the universe implode from such sorcery?